# Microsoft Graph API - User response JSON not complete

Tags: php, json, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

The company I work for needs to develop an API that will export Office 365 contacts and import them into our user profile's contacts. This runs as some sort of daemon.

I found Microsoft's Graph API and been working on it for days to get it running, but the GET contacts function doesn't seem to work for me.

I'm using the resource `graph.microsoft.com` and trying to get contacts with 
`/users/{id}/contacts` using PHP cURL.

```
stdClass Object
(
    [error] => stdClass Object
        (
            [code] => ResourceNotFound
            [message] => Resource could not be discovered.
            [innerError] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [request-id] => 134b1964-9421-4fce-84ba-aca1525c705e
                    [date] => 2017-03-20T15:35:39
                )

        )

)
```

I'm getting an access token just fine (my app currently requests all read/write permissions to avoid being stuck because of missing privileges and they have been consented to by an admin account).

I've found out that the reason to this is probably because the User response JSON isn't completely formatted as it's supposed to be. [Microsoft's Documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/user#json-representation) shows a full representation of the User resource. Mine seems to be missing all the relationships with other resources, like "contacts" that I need. Here's the JSON I get from the Graph API using `/users/{id}`:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [@odata.context] => https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#users(contacts)/$entity
    [id] => e4007399-90fb-489d-a0f8-2c577f219638
    [accountEnabled] => 1
    [assignedLicenses] => Array
        (
        )

    [assignedPlans] => Array
        (
        )

    [businessPhones] => Array
        (
        )

    [city] => 
    [companyName] => 
    [country] => 
    [department] => 
    [displayName] => Loic Didelot
    [givenName] => Loic
    [jobTitle] => 
    [mail] => 
    [mailNickname] => vendors_mixvoip.com#EXT#
    [mobilePhone] => 
    [onPremisesDomainName] => 
    [onPremisesImmutableId] => 
    [onPremisesLastSyncDateTime] => 
    [onPremisesSecurityIdentifier] => 
    [onPremisesSamAccountName] => 
    [onPremisesSyncEnabled] => 
    [onPremisesUserPrincipalName] => 
    [passwordPolicies] => 
    [passwordProfile] => 
    [officeLocation] => 
    [postalCode] => 
    [preferredLanguage] => 
    [provisionedPlans] => Array
        (
        )

    [proxyAddresses] => Array
        (
        )

    [refreshTokensValidFromDateTime] => 2017-03-14T09:13:10Z
    [showInAddressList] => 
    [imAddresses] => Array
        (
        )

    [state] => 
    [streetAddress] => 
    [surname] => Didelot
    [usageLocation] => 
    [userPrincipalName] => vendors_mixvoip.com#EXT#@vendorsmixvoip.onmicrosoft.com
    [userType] => Member
)
```

I haven't been able to find how to solve this, when I try searching for this problem, I get results for "custom properties" that can be selected by using `/users/{id}?$select=customPropertyName`. This doesn't work for `/users/{id}?$select=contacts`.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Graph explorer is your friend (easy way to try out REST requests to the API):  https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer

Also if you look at the front page of our documentation overview, there are some example queries (although contacts is not one of them) that'll give you some ideas: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs

Anyway - the call you need to make is

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id}/contacts
```

This returns the user/{id}'s set/collection of personal contacts.  The resource  type (for the collection) is a `contact` and not a `user`.

For more information on contact resource type and List contacts see the following topics:
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/contact
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_list_contacts

Hope this helps,

Comment: I have tried Graph explorer but it won't let me sign in with the user I've registered the app with. You might not have read my whole Post, I **am** using ´GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id}/contacts´ to get the contacts, but it doesn't work, I'm getting the error ´Resource could not be described´. Searching this error did not help and it has led me to think that the returned user JSON isn't complete as it's not the same as the documented user JSON.

Comment: Did you register with a Microsoft Account? If so, yes we are having a few issues with this, so that capability was disabled. Can you update your question with a full error message (including request-id and timestamp) please?  Does this fail for all users? Is it possible that the user you are trying to fetch personal contacts for doesn't have a Exchange Online license/mailbox?

Comment: I did not register the app with a Microsoft Account. Is this a must? In that case, why am I able to do all the steps without it? (I did update the post with the error response on 20th)